# Price mismatch on careers cv page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The price on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv is different to the price on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/jobseekers ($19 vs $9).

I think $19 was the old price and it's just not been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this was a typo. It's been updated.

Comment: It's still/again wrong now. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq says $19, the actual credit card data entry screen says $19! But it's only $9, as shown on the emailed receipt and https://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/jobseekers