# Price mismatch on careers cv page: Part 2 (Revenge of the Price Mismatch)

Tags: support, jobs

[This problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54815/price-mismatch-on-careers-cv-page) still isn't fixed. I just filed my CV and paid $9, but much of the documentation on the page says that a year costs $19. I'm not complaining about paying less, but, *regression, dude!*

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. Not all special offers are reflected in the page.

Comment: Special offers? Am I _special_, Jeff? `*wink*`